# Why am I getting errors when trying to invoke Django Python shell?

Tags: django, python-2.7, windows-7

My current version of python is 2.7.10 and version of Django is 1.9.1, path.py is 8.1.2 but every time when I'm trying to invoke python shell by command: 
`$ python manage.py shell` I'm getting a lot of errors and the ending of them looks like:

```
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "W:\SVN\vendors\python\win32\lib\site-packages\IPython\CrashHandler.py", line 157, in __call__
    report.write(self.make_report(traceback))
  File "W:\SVN\vendors\python\win32\lib\site-packages\IPython\CrashHandler.py", line 215, in make_report
    rpt_add('BZR revision   : %s \n\n' % Release.revision)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'revision'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "W:\SVN\vendors\python\win32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "W:\SVN\vendors\python\win32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "W:\SVN\vendors\python\win32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "W:\SVN\vendors\python\win32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "W:\SVN\vendors\python\win32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\shell.py", line 69, in handle
    self.run_shell(shell=options['interface'])
  File "W:\SVN\vendors\python\win32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\shell.py", line 58, in run_shell
    return getattr(self, shell)()
  File "W:\SVN\vendors\python\win32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\shell.py", line 41, in ipython
    ip()
  File "W:\SVN\vendors\python\win32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\shell.py", line 22, in _ipython_pre_011
    shell = IPShell(argv=[])
  File "W:\SVN\vendors\python\win32\lib\site-packages\IPython\Shell.py", line 73, in __init__
    debug=debug,shell_class=shell_class)
  File "W:\SVN\vendors\python\win32\lib\site-packages\IPython\ipmaker.py", line 521, in make_IPython
    IP.pre_config_initialization()
  File "W:\SVN\vendors\python\win32\lib\site-packages\IPython\iplib.py", line 835, in pre_config_initialization
    self.db = pickleshare.PickleShareDB(rc.ipythondir + "/db")
  File "W:\SVN\vendors\python\win32\lib\site-packages\IPython\Extensions\pickleshare.py", line 53, in __init__
    if not self.root.isdir():
TypeError: _isdir() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

How can I overcome the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From doing a quick search, it looks like this error happens when both Django and IPython are installed, since apparently Django will attempt to use the IPython shell.

The first resource with someone who had a similar issue:

> [run python manage.py shell occurs errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16640660/run-python-manage-py-shell-occurs-errors)

And in the link above, one of the comments on the OP's question suggested looking at this separate thread for answers:

> https://superuser.com/questions/318655/error-running-ipython3-on-xp-typeerror-isdir-takes-exactly-1-argument-0-gi

The winning answer says the following:

> Finally decided to give this another stab, and managed to get it to
>   work. The solution is a two-line change in the
>   ipython-0.11-py3.2.egg\IPython\utils\pickleshare.py file, line 52:
>
> Before:
>
> ```
> if not self.root.isdir():
>     self.root.makedirs()
> ```
>
> After:
>
> ```
> if not os.path.isdir(self.root):
>         os.makedirs(self.root)
> ```

Comment: Yes! This is solution!
Thank you for your help!